# NetSuite Field Formula issue with Concat (SQL)

Tags: mysql, netsuite

I'm having an issue with a NetSuite workflow which uses an SQL formula to concatenate two custom fields. The issue is that on some entries one of those fields is missing. The formula i am using is

{custitem3}||' '||{custitemshoewidth}

When "custitem3" is not present on the form I am given the error "ERROR: Field 'custitem3' Not Found" I tried using a conditional IF statement and a WHEN. I'm not familiar with SQL so it could be my syntax. But if anyone could advise it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Thank you for your input. I have found the issue. Referencing a field that doesn't exist regardless of whether it is actually called will create the ERROR. So my work around was to create a new field that references the the matrix field that may or may not be present.

Referencing this field - which will always be present on the item record will not cause an ERROR report to fill the field trying to concatenate it and if the reference field contains an error report, it can be ignored. I tried this code modified from what YNK suggested

```
CASE 
WHEN {custitem_hm_ref1} ISNUMERIC 
{custitemshoewidth}||" "||{custitem_hm_ref1} 
ELSE {custitemshoewidth} 
END
```

But this is returning an invalid expression. Did I adjust the code wrong?

Comment: After reviewing and testing several things. It seems that the bigger issue here is the "custiitem3" field not existing on this form. Does anyone have a suggestion for getting around that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE Function instead of IF condition here..

Like this :

```
CASE
WHEN {custitem3} IS NULL THEN
    {custitemshoewidth}
ELSE
    {custitem3}||' '||{custitemshoewidth}
END
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @YNK
I tried running the workflow with the CASE WHEN statement. It kicked back the same error ERROR: Field 'custitem3' Not Found. 
I believe it has to do with calling on a field that doesn't exist on that form (custitem3 is a matrix field, this error is found on none matrix items.) My thought on a workaround is creating a field that pulls from the matrix. If there is an error in that field then the code you listed may work by not pulling the error, only none error text. 
CASE
WHEN {custitemX} ISNUMERIC
    {custitem3}||' '||{custitemshoewidth}
ELSE
    {custitemshoewidth}
END

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for one of the `NVL` functions. There are `NVL` and `NVL2` functions available for handling null values. To accomplish what you're doing, I might use a formula like:

`NVL2({custitem3}, {custitem3}||' '||{custitemshoewidth}, {custitemshoewidth})`

For more details on all the available SQL functions, see the NS Help doc titled "SQL Expressions".